# @RefreshScope and /refresh not working

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-config

I have tried to implement spring external configurations using Config Server. It is working fine for the very first time when the application is started but any changes to the properties file are not being reflected. I tried to use /refresh endpoint to refresh my properties on the fly but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help on this would be greatly helpful.

I tried POSTing to localhost:8080/refresh but getting a 404 Error response.

Below is the code of my application class

```
   @SpringBootApplication
public class Config1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Config1Application.class, args);
    }
}

@RestController
@RefreshScope
class MessageRestController {

    @Value("${message:Hello default}")
    private String message;

    @RequestMapping("/message")
    String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
}
```

and POM file is

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.M8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

and bootstrap.properties

```
spring.application.name=xxx
spring.cloud.config.uri=https://xxxxxx.com
management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The endpoint is now `/actuator/refresh` for Spring 2 and greater

**From the comments:**

- You do need to have the `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh` set in the `bootstrap.properties/bootstrap.yml`

**Note:** If you're new to `Spring-Cloud` and not quite sure of what all keywords can go in `web.exposure` you can set it to `*` (`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`) to have all exposed and you can get to know the endpoints and their restrictions later.

Comment: Thanks spencergibb. Even the above mentioned end point did not work earlier. I have updated the spring-cloud-dependencies version to Edgware.RELEASE and spring-boot-starter-parent to 1.5.10.RELEASE and it started working. Guess the issue was due to the versions.

Comment: No. You need set management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=* (or a list of endpoints to enable)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I have reverted the versions to the latest and added the above property. Now I am able to see the latest values using above endpoint.

Comment: `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh` would work too.

Comment: if my app has 100 instances in the cloud, do I need to actually make a GET call to all 100 /actuator/refresh?

Comment: @KalpeshSoni that is what spring cloud bus is for.

Comment: @spencergibb So we have few beans with refershscope and consul `ConfigWatch`. Every time we change the key value it is refreshing the key values and also other beans which we dont need to refresh. Is there a way to only refersh key value and not other beans ? Thanks

Comment: @user2683814 not currently. I'd remove `@RefreshScope` and listen for the application event `EnvironmentChangeEvent`, see if the keys you want are there and deal with the changes manually.

Comment: @spencergibb, 3+ years later, is there now a way to only refresh what is needed(I am using `Spring Boot 2.7.x`)? Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking @jumping_monkey and if it's related to this question

Comment: No worries @spencergibb, found my answer. Thanks for replying and being there for the community(as always). Cheers mate.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me after adding the property

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

In bootstrap.properties and changing the url to `/actuator/refresh` for spring version above 2.0.0
For spring version 1.0.5 url is `/refresh`.

Comment: Aside from this S/O post, where is this documented?

Comment: @acidnbass details docs is at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

Answer (score 4):

For **YAML** files, the property's value needs to be wrapped inside double quotes :

```
# Spring Boot Actuator
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Note : Ensure you use the right *endpoints* keyword (with 's') for this property as long as it exists for another property without 's' : "management.endpoint.health.... " .

Answer (score 0):

Note: - It's a POST request (not GET)

I've posted the solution here

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/74465108/2171938][1]

Answer (score 0):

```
For me, after executing /actuator/refresh, the @value("property") did not change (even after changing values in GitHub application.properties).but Using environment.getProperty('property') I am obtaining dynamic values from the GitHub after executing /actuator/refresh.   

From the below example I obesrved that environment.getProperty("enableEmailAlerts") giving latest values after every /actuator/refresh execution. 

@RestController
@RefreshScope
@RequestMapping(path = "/producer/api")
public class ProducerController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Value("${enableEmailAlerts}")
    private String enableEmailAlerts;

    @GetMapping(path = "/test")
    public void getPropertyDetails(){
        System.out.println("enableEmailAlerts-"+enableEmailAlerts);
        System.out.println("alerts-"+environment.getProperty("enableEmailAlerts"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

If you have issues with accepting formurlencoded in SPRING 2.0>, use :

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {} http://localhost:port/actuator/refresh

instead of:

curl -d {} http://localhost:port/refresh

which was accepted in SPRING 1.*