# actuator /refresh is not being provided in SpringBoot 2.0.1

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

I am creating a demo project for `Spring-Config-Server` and `Spring-Config-Client`.

In `SpringBoot 1.5.6.RELEASE` everything is working fine.

However, when I am upgrading project to `2.0.1.RELEASE` it does not provide the actuator endpoints.

---

Actuator endpoint provided in **1.5.6.RELEASE**

```
Mapped "{[/refresh || /refresh.json],methods=[POST]}"
Mapped "{[/dump || /dump.json],methods=[GET]
Mapped "{[/heapdump || /heapdump.json],methods=[GET]
Mapped "{[/autoconfig || /autoconfig.json],methods=[GET]
Mapped "{[/resume || /resume.json],methods=[POST]}"
Mapped "{[/configprops || /configprops.json],methods=[GET]
Mapped "{[/features || /features.json],methods=[GET]
Mapped "{[/loggers/{name:.*}],methods=[GET]
Mapped "{[/restart || /restart.json],methods=[POST]}"
...and many more
```

---

Actuator endpoint provided in **2.0.1.RELEASE**

```
Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET]
Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET]
Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET]
```

---

**pom.xml** : `2.0.1.RELEASE`

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RC1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

The only difference bw `1.5.6` pom is version and `spring-cloud.version = Dalston.SR2`

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After a bit of research, I have found the cause why the endpoints are not shown in `Spring Boot 2.0` is [as per the spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.exposing)

> Since Endpoints may contain sensitive information, you should carefully consider when to expose them. The following table shows the default exposure for the built-in endpoints:

so, we need to expose them manually.

I have added `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*` in `application.properties` file and now all the actuator endpoints are exposed via HTTP .

**Note**: If you are using `.yml` make sure to use `"*"` not `*`

We can also exclude actuator which we don't want to expose using the property `management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude= shutdown,liquibase`

Comment: Hm, that's really weird. The docs state that the endpoints are *enabled* by default, which was definitely not the case for me (and it seems for you too!). Perhaps the docs are wrong?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between enabled and exposed via web endpoint. Enabled endpoint is not necessarily exposed via web. Currently by default most endpoints are enabled. Most of them are also exposed via JMX, but only "info" and "health" are exposed via web (http). Documentation clearly states all of this if you read it.

Answer (score 8):

`refresh` endpoint can be enabled to use via web (exposed via web), using this in `application.yaml`

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include: health,info,refresh
```

Spring Boot enables `health` and `info` endpoints by default. It is necessary to list them to keep them enabled.

If your application has this URL http://localhost:8181

You can send `POST` request to refresh

http://localhost:8181/actuator/refresh

Comment: does ur application restart when u hit http://localhost:8181/actuator/refresh ?

Comment: @SanjayNaik No. Context restarts.

Answer (score 7):

Exposure of endpoints on HTTP is now configurable by using properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude
```

You can expose endpoints by there ID mentioned by Actuator.

```
# Include all endpoints 
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
# Exclude specifics 
management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=env
```

Answer (score 6):

Even after adding the below line, it wont help sometimes

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`

Try this:-
Refresh works on `OPTIONS` method, not with `POST` method for few cases.

[image]

Comment: options mainly give 200. But, it works for POST only, are you sure it overrided values?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.
Enabled all the endpoints by setting

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

And sent an empty request to refresh endpoint.

```
curl -d '{}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8000/actuator/refresh
```

URL http://localhost:8000/actuator/ will list all the available endpoints.

P.S.: My app is running on port 8000. On default port 8080, I am running Config server.

Answer (score 0):

To enable refresh, add following properties to your application properties file

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,refresh 
management.endpoint.refresh.enabled=true
```