# spring cloud refresh ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, refresh, spring-cloud, endpoints, configurationproperties

I want to rebinding `ConfigurationProperties` data.Read user documentation.
`post http://localhost:8080/env`,It working .
But `post http://localhost:8080/env/reset`,Cannot refresh all configurations.
Can only refresh keys that have visited `/env`.
I want to refresh all the configuration what should I do?

http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting key-value pairs to `/env` will trigger `rebinding`. 
Posting to `/env/reset` will trigger too on condition that `manager` propertysource not empty.

If you are not updating environment by posting `/env`, you can use endpoint `/refresh`.

```
@ManagedOperation
public Map<String, Object> reset() {
    Map<String, Object> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(map);
    if (!map.isEmpty()) {
        map.clear();
        publish(new EnvironmentChangeEvent(publisher, result.keySet()));
    }
    return result;
}

@ManagedOperation
public void setProperty(String name, String value) {

    if (!environment.getPropertySources().contains(MANAGER_PROPERTY_SOURCE)) {
        synchronized (map) {
            if (!environment.getPropertySources().contains(MANAGER_PROPERTY_SOURCE)) {
                MapPropertySource source = new MapPropertySource(
                        MANAGER_PROPERTY_SOURCE, map);
                environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(source);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!value.equals(environment.getProperty(name))) {
        map.put(name, value);
        publish(new EnvironmentChangeEvent(publisher, Collections.singleton(name)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
`/actuator/refresh`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311068/refreshscope-and-refresh-not-working