# Spring cloud config with database backend

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I'm trying to setup a spring boot project with Spring Cloud Config with database backend. I've following things in my setup:

```
application.properties
spring.application.name=my-services-api
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2

spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=5000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

spring.profiles.active=jdbc

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8080
spring.cloud.config.server.default-profile=production
spring.cloud.config.server.default-label=latest
spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.sql=SELECT key, value FROM my_properties WHERE application=? AND profile=? AND label=?;
spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.order=1


spring.h2.console.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh

message=default message
```

And I've `@EnableConfigServer` in application class.  Also I've `@RefreshScope` in a controller where I'm trying to inject a value from my database.

```
@Value("${message}")
private String message;
```

And I've an entry in db.

```
APPLICATION     |PROFILE    |LABEL      |KEY        |VALUE  
my-services-api |production |latest     |message    |Some New Hello
```

To refresh I'm doing a POST in `/actuator/refresh` with empty body which returns a success 200. But the value of `message` field is still the one coming from properties file and is not updated.

When I go a GET `/my-services-api/production/latest`, I see the new value in the response but `message` field is still not refreshed. Am I missing any configuration? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share code for the class which has `private String message` ?

Comment: `@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class MessageController {
 @Value("${message}")
 private String message;
 
 @RequestMapping("/message")
 String message() {
  return message;
 }

}`

Comment: Have you tried the solution in this thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311068/refreshscope-and-refresh-not-working

Comment: can you add your pom.xml as well

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the configuration to have a separate server and client:

On the server side, I have this in application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=my-services-api
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.platform=h2

spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=5000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

spring.profiles.active=jdbc

spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8080
spring.cloud.config.server.default-profile=jdbc
spring.cloud.config.server.default-label=latest
spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.sql=SELECT key, value FROM my_properties WHERE application=? AND profile=? AND label=?;
spring.cloud.config.server.jdbc.order=1


spring.h2.console.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh


logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core=TRACE
```

On the client side, I've a bootstrap.properties with:

```
spring.application.name=my-services-api
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8080
spring.cloud.config.label=latest
spring.cloud.config.profile=jdbc
```

And application.properties with:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh
```

To refresh, I did a POST call to /actuator/refresh on the client service.

Comment: Hi, I tried this way, But my client says cannot resolve property message. Can you help me here?