# Load properties from application.properties in Spring Cloud Config until refreshed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I've a setup with Spring Cloud Config Server and Client as described in the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143361/spring-cloud-config-with-database-backend). The next thing I'm trying to do is load the properties from application.properties in the client when the service starts. Once I call /actuator/refresh I would like to load it from the Config Server. Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use @RefreshScope annotation I think. Look at this guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Comment: Same issue with @RefreshScope. It directly loads from db